# Detect a touch on a certain object in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, touch

What's the Xcode code for this pseudocode?

```
if ([Any UIPickerView in my ViewController isTouched]) {
    [AnyUIView setHidden:NO];
}

if ([Any UIPickerView in my ViewController is__NOT__Touched__Anymore__]) {
    [AnyUIView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Tried it with the `-(void)touchesBegan`method, it detects the touches but I was not able to make it object-specific. Thanks

P.S. I want to display a hint on the display while the `UIPickerView`is touched.

Comment: What's the point of displaying a hint _after_ your user has pressed on a control?

Comment: Reminding him of what unit he has to pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just from the top of my head...... but you should be able to get the idea...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass: UIPickerView.class]) {
         //your touch was in a uipickerview ... do whatever you have to do
    }
}
```

..and do the same with `touchesEnded:withEvent:`